# Java PDFBox, extract data from a column of a table

Tags: java, pdfbox

I would like to find out how to extract from this pdf(ex. image) http://postimg.org/image/ypebht5dx/

For example, I want to extract only the values ​​in the column "TENSIONE[V]" and if it encounters a blank cell I enter the letter "X" in the output.
How could I do?

The code I used is this:

```
 PDDocument p=PDDocument.load(new File("a.pdf"));
 PDFTextStripper t=new PDFTextStripper();
 System.out.println(t.getText(p));
```

and I get this output:

http://s23.postimg.org/wbhcrw03v/Immagine.png

Comment: The image you are showing is the test output given by `System.out.println(t.getText(p));`?

Comment: No, it is extracted only text!

Comment: Well as you already extracted text then you can do some String operation and get your required parts. You can use [PDFTextStripper API](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/util/PDFTextStripper.html). It has getLineSeperateor

Comment: but if you just want the data in a particular column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just guidelines. Use them upon your use. This is not tested either, but help you solve your issue. If you have any question let me know.

```
String text = t.getText(p);
String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n"); // give you all the lines separated by new line

String cols[] = lines[0].split("\\s+") // gives array separated by whitespaces
// cols[0] contains pins
// clos[1] contains TENSIONE[V]
// cols[2] contains TOLLRENZA if not present then its empty
```