# Java PDFBox, extract data from a particular line of a table

Tags: java, pdfbox, text-extraction

I've got a tiny question you surely will clear in 30 seconds!  ;-)

I try to read a particular line of a .PDF timetable.

**Example:**

```
New York:   06:30  /  07:00  /  10:15  /  12:30

Boston:     07:30  /  08:00  /  11:15  /  01:30

Chicago:    08:30  /  09:00  /  12:15  /  02:30
```

I refer to that [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16217999/java-pdfbox-extract-data-from-a-column-of-a-table) and try to adapt it, but it doesn't work!

If I understand well the comment at the end of the line

```
String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n"); // give you all the lines separated by new line
```

in my case `String lines[] = text.split("Boston");` should retrieve all the Boston columns, but it is not the case.

So how could I retrieve all the Boston times (07:30, 08:00, 11:15, 01:30, and so on)?

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

I am obviously speaking about natives pdfbox functions

Otherwise, I can analyse line by line the extracted text from the PDF file, of course, but I guess it would not be quiet optimized/fast.

Answer (score 0):

> If I understand well the comment at the end of the line
>
> ```
> String lines[] = text.split("\\r?\\n"); // give you all the lines separated by new line
> ```
>
> in my case `String lines[] = text.split("Boston");` should retrieve all the Boston columns, but it is not the case.

No, your operations splits `text` at each occurrence of the String "Boston". In your case, therefore, it results in two Strings

```
New York:   06:30  /  07:00  /  10:15  /  12:30
```

and

```
:     07:30  /  08:00  /  11:15  /  01:30

Chicago:    08:30  /  09:00  /  12:15  /  02:30
```

> So how could I retrieve all the Boston times (07:30, 08:00, 11:15, 01:30, and so on)?

Search the `String text` for the substring "Boston:", get the following substring up to the next end-of-line, and split it around slash characters.

> I am obviously speaking about natives pdfbox functions

No. You started by talking about `split` which is a method of the Java `String` class, and your task as you present it is pure String analysis in Java.

If you were talking about Pdfbox functions, you'd focus on customizing the `PdfTextStripper`.

As you don't know where the Boston lines are before the text is extracted, though, there is hardly anything you can before the text is extracted.